# Argument over an induction proof

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics

My friend gave me a problem.

> Define a sequence $\langle a_n \rangle$ by the recurrence relation :$$ a_{n+2} - 6a_{n+1} + 8a_n = 0 $$ and
>   $a_1 = 4, a_2 = 8 $. Find the general term $a_n$ in closed form.

By inspection, I got the general term as $ a_n = 2^{n+1} $. Then I proved it using induction. However, he says that the proof isn't elegant!

1. He questions the source of my induction hypothesis: "how did you get that in the first place?".
2. He says that he is fine with the induction proof, but he *isn't satisfied*. He asks as to how I know that $a_n = 2^{n+1} $ is the only solution.

We had a heated argument over this matter. Now, what's wrong with what I did?!?

---

Btw, my proof:

**Hypothesis:** $P(n)$ = " $a_n = 2^{n+1} $ is the $n$*th* term of the given sequence."

**Assumption**: Assume that $ P(i),\; \forall\; i \in \{1,2,...k-1\} $ to be true.

**To prove $P(k)$:**

We know that $a_k = 6a_{k-1} - 8a_{k-2}$. Also, from our assumption, we have $a_{k-1} = 2^k$ and $a_{k-2} = 2^{k-1}$. Plugging that in the relation gives us $a_k = 2^{k+1}$.

**Conclusion**:
$P(k)$ is true if $ P(i),\; \forall\; i \in \{1,2,...k-1\} $. $P(1)$ is true. So $P(2)$ is true, and so on.

Therefore, $P(n)$ is true $\forall\; n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence proved.

Comment: First use this(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving)  to find $a_n$

Comment: I know that there are techniques to solve such relations. (I myself didn't know of any though, so thanks for the link!). However, what's wrong with what I did? He just doesn't wanna agree that what I did was 'good'!

Comment: imo guessing is just fine. as to uniqueness of the solution - your sequence is uniquely determined by its first two terms since you can compute all the others using the requerence relation.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this proof - a little guesswork is always good. Also, you have shown (inadvertently, perhaps) that this is the only solution.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, I don't understand how I proved that this is the only solution. Awkward situation! How is it the only solution?

Comment: Suppose $(a_n)$ is any solution. By definition $a_1 = 4, a_2 = 8$. By induction (as you have proved), $a_n = 2^{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your proof.  But when your friend says it is "not satisfying", there is nothing wrong with that, either.

Comment: The only thing wrong with your proof is that, if the problem had been $a_{n+2}-6a_{n+1}+7a_n=0$, you would not have been able to guess a solution; ditto, had it been $a_{n+2}-6a_{n+1}+8a_n=0$, with $a_1=4$, $a_2=5$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, the thing is, he says that I proved $a_n = 2^{n+1}$ is *a* solution. How do I prove that it is *the* solution? That's what he wants it seems!...In fact, he said what I was doing was like hypothesizing " $x = 1, -2$ are the roots of $x^2 + x - 2 = 0$" and then showing that they are the roots by substitution. "This doesn't give all solutions to the quadratic!"

Comment: @GEdgar, I don't understand what's "not satisfying" here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, but then that doesn't make my proof wrong. My proof was for this problem! What you are suggesting (and he said the same) is a completely different problem. That time I won't give this proof! If there's an easy problem, why complicate it?

Comment: Sometimes a more complicated proof yields more insight (such as how to solve similar problems).  Then it is a matter of judgement which proof is "better".

Comment: What do you want from me? You asked a question, I answered it. You don't like my answer, well, your friend doesn't like your answer. What goes around, comes around.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, that was witty! Fine. So I'd just stop all this here.

Comment: @GEdgar, that's right. No doubt.

Comment: Although it is obvious, you have to show that your formula is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$ (the induction basis is missing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for minor formulation quibbles, your proof is a valid proof that $2^{n+1}$ is the only solution to the recurrence.

The minor quibble is that instead of making your induction hypothesis be "$a_n=2^{n+1}$ is the $n$th term of the given sequence", it would be more rigorous to make it "If $(a_k)_{k\ge 1}$ is any sequence that satisfies the recurrence, then $a_n=2^{n+1}$". Then what you have is a proof by induction on $n$ that every sequence that satisfies your recurrence is equal to the particular sequence $2^{n+1}$.

Strictly speaking you *also* need to prove that $2^{n+1}$ is a solution at all (because your induction proof *assumes* that you already have a sequence that solves the recurrence). But that proof is as simple as plugging $2^{n+1}$ into the recurrence relation and simplifying. No induction is needed there.

Comment: "Strictly speaking you also need to prove that 2n+1 is a solution at all". I don't understand. Haven't I proved that very thing? From what I understand, I guessed that $a_n = 2^{n+1}$. With induction, I proved it. So how have I not proved that $2^{n+1}$ is a solution at all?

Comment: @ParthThakkar: No, because your induction proof assumes that the recurrence has a solution at all. _Under that assumption_ you have proved that this solution has to be $2^{n+1}$. But you need an argument external to the induction proof to show that there _is_ any solution that you can prove equals $2^{n+1}$.

Comment: Ok. But then doesn't the other method do the same? The standard way (as shown by wikipedia and also by egreg) does assume $x^n$ to be a solution. I agree that such an assumption is 'smaller in magnitude' than my 'direct' assumption, but still...assumption! So don't we need to prove there too that the recurrence has a solution too...?

Comment: @ParthThakkar: I'm not sure what "the standard way" you're referring to is, but it is quite likely that it leaves the proof that such-and-such _is_ a solution to the reader -- it's usually just a matter of plugging into the recurrence and simplifying. And usually the simplifications are _the same_ simplifications as you're doing in the induction step anyway. My point is just that you need to do them again, _outside_ the induction framework, in order to have a formally complete proof.

Comment: Ok. So you are saying that *after* doing this induction, I have to plug in the terms of the sequence in the recurrence relation and then show that the relation holds. Am I right?

Comment: @ParthThakkar: Yes, either before or after. That will be enough to show that $2^{n+1}$ _is_ a solution; the induction is for showing it's the _only_ one.

Answer (score 2):

Finding the closed form of a recurrence relation always involves some guessing; in the case of a relation like
$$
a_{n+2}+ba_{n+1}+ca_{n}=0
$$
one can, as a first approximation, try finding whether $x^n$ can be used. It can if, for all $n$,
$$
x^{n+2}+bx^{n+1}+cx^n=0.
$$
Excluding $x=0$ that would be trivial and surely doesn't satisfy your initial conditions, we get
$$
x^2+bx+c=0.
$$

Oh! Wait! In our case this means $x^2-6x+8=0$, that is $x=2$ or $x=4$.

Now, if $\langle a_n\rangle$ and $\langle b_n\rangle$ satisfy the general recurrence (no initial condition, for the moment), also $\langle\alpha a_n+\beta b_n\rangle$ satisfies it. So we can try
$$
a_n=\alpha\cdot 2^n + \beta\cdot 4^n
$$
Setting $a_1=4$ and $a_2=8$ we get
\begin{cases}
2\alpha+4\beta=4\\
4\alpha+16\beta=8
\end{cases}
and this implies $\alpha=2$ and $\beta=0$.

Hey! I did it! My closed form is $a_n=2\cdot 2^n=2^{n+1}$. It surely satisfies our conditions and there is *at most one* sequence satisfying them, because once you know $a_1$ and $a_2$, you know $a_3=6a_2-8a_1$; then you know $a_4=6a_3-8a_4$ and so on.

End of the story! If you have a recurrence relation of the form
$$
a_{n+k}+b_1a_{n+k-1}+\dots+b_ka_n=0
$$
and the polynomial
$$
x^k+b_1x^k+\dots+b_{k-1}x+b_k
$$
has $k$ distinct real roots $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_k$, then any sequence satisfying the recurrence relation is of the form
$$
a_n=\alpha_1 r_1^n+\alpha_2 r_2^n+\dots+\alpha_k r_k^n
$$
and you can determine $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k$ by the $k$ initial conditions.

It's a bit more complicated with complex roots or repeated roots, but not really too much.